# boot log as it appears on screen

Tags: boot, log

is there a way to see a boot log as it appears on screen having removed "quiet-splash" directive from /etc/default/grub?

I mean: I've tried with journalctl -b -1 (and so on) but is a huge lot of information and I haven't been able to find the line in which hostname is set up (that's what I'm looking for).

EDIT: I've forgotten to say that I need it on a live CD: during boot, is showed a line that starts with "Welcome to Ubuntu ...": is there a way to find it in any log file?

Thanks and cheers,
Sil

Comment: hostname is set by systemd: `systemctl status systemd-hostnamed.service`